# MS Word. Auto-update labels in figures

Tags: microsoft-word, label

I'm thinking this is beyond the scope of MS Word, but hopefully, someone can help.
I occasionally need to write patent documents. They require a separate figures document. These figures are often block-diagrams with the requirement that each block is numbered, related to the figure number.  For example, (see attachment) Figure 1 would show the blocks labeled 11, 12, 13... 1N. Figure 2 would have blocks 21, 22, 23... 2N etc.

If a new figure is inserted, all the figure numbers below need to increment by one, but also, the labels in those figures need to increase (21 --> 31, 31-->41 ... XN-->(X+1)N )

Is there a way to link the label numbers to the figure number so that these updates happen automatically?

I've searched everywhere but can't find anything remotely close to this, except for updating Figure labels.
Thank you.

[Block Diagram Labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmK5b.png)

Comment: It might be possible but "fully automatic" is unlikely, i.e. you might have to open documents and update some fields. But, just to get a handle on the problem, do you have 1 "patent document" and 1 "figures document"/ Or could you have 1 "patent document" and several "figures documents". Or could you have multiple "patent documents" for a patent and "multiple figures documents". Finally, are you allowed to use VBA?

Comment: The final goal is to have one written document which explains each figure in a separate figure document. 
I don't mind doing some collating at the end to achieve this goal. What would be really useful is to avoid the steps in currently doing. 
1. Make figure with reference labels. 
2. Copy it on to the figure doc. 
3. Write a description in the main doc. 
4. If a figure needs adding, remake every image after that point with incremented reference labels.
5. Modify the main document to maintain consistency. 

Appreciate any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited this a little as I thought of a simpler approach that might work as long as your "patent document" is quite small, and JeeHaa has now posted an Answer with the other main approach I considered. I didn't cover that because it's arguably less useful if you have multiple diagram documents and I'm still not sure what the situation is there.

In the case where you have quite a small "main document" a possible approach that solves most problems is to use

- an INCLUDETEXT field to include the entire text of the main document in each of the diagram documents
- a mechanism to hide the text of the main document
- REF fields to reference the diagram numbers

So what do I mean by a "small document"? Well, what I really mean is a document that is small enough that Word will not take a very long time to re-include the document and redo its pagination.

e.g., let's suppose your main document is called c:\xxx\maindoc1.docx and you are inserting standard Figure captions with no chapter numbering.

That means that Word will insert a figure number using a single field code like this:

```
{ SEQ Figure \* Arabic }
```

(You can toggle between "field code" view and "field results" view using Alt-F9 in the Windows Desktop version of Word. You can update the result of a field code by selecting it and pressing F9; You can insert a pair of the special "field code braces" {  } using ctrl-F9)

To include the text of maindoc1 in a diagram document, you can click at the beginning of the body of the diagram document then

- use ctrl-F9 to insert a pair of special field code braces {  }
- between them, type

  ```
   INCLUDETEXT "c:\\xxx\\maindoc1.docx"
  ```

so you see

```
    { INCLUDETEXT "c:\\xxx\\maindoc1.docx" }
```

(Alternatively, you can go to *Insert tab->Text group->object dropdown->Insert text from File*. Locate and select maindoc1.text. Then click the small dropdown on the right of the *Insert* button and click the *Insert as Link* option.)

Now select the INCLUDETEXT field and use ctrl-F9 so you have

```
    { { INCLUDETEXT "c:\\xxx\\maindoc1.docx" } }
```

and type `SET F` after the first `{` so you have

```
    { SET F { INCLUDETEXT "c:\\xxx\\maindoc1.docx" } }
```

Select the fields and use F9 to update them. Using the SET means that you have included the document text etc but it is in effect invisible.

As an example of how to make a reference to your figure number, in the main document, select the first figure number and use the Ribbon Home tab->Links group->Bookmark to add a bookmark that "covers" the number. You'll have to give it a unique name. Although using a sequence in the name can be confusing using something like that is probably the easiest way to do it. But perhaps use something like Fig00100.

To make a reference to your Figure number, in your diagram use the field code

```
{ Fig000 }
```

You can then type 1, 2, 3 etc after that to provide the shape number as I outlined in my original text below. You can switch to File->Print and back to update these numbers.

You will still have to open each diagram document and update all the fields etc. to ensure you have the correct numbers.

An advantage of using an INCLUDETEXT field rather than a LINK field is that Word does not destroy fields nested inside an INCLUDETEXT field. Depending on the file system being used, that may mean you can avoid the problem where you move your documents to another folder, and the INCLUDETEXT field then points to the wrong place.

To do that for a situation where the diagram document(s) is/are in the same folder as the main document, instead of

```
{ SET F { INCLUDETEXT "c:\\xxx\\maindoc1.docx" } }
```

use the following

```
{ SET F { INCLUDETEXT "{ FILENAME \p }\\..\\maindoc1.docx" } }
```

**This is the beginning of my original Answer**
There are a couple of broad-brush approaches that you could at least try. All use Word fields, and rely on the fact that you can insert fields into graphic objects (the text area of a shape, or a text box). So you would have to be creating and maintaining your diagrams in Word for this to have any chance of working.

Let's start with an example. Suppose your "main document" (containing the figure numbers) is in c:\xxx\maindoc1.docx. I am assuming that you are numbering your figures using the standard Word figure numbering feature, and to simplify, that you are not including "chapter numbering" with the Figure numbering. I'm assuming you have one "diagram document" for now, and that you are starting with an empty document.

That means that Word will insert a figure number using a single field code like this:

```
{ SEQ Figure \* Arabic }
```

(You can toggle between "field code" view and "field results" view using Alt-F9 in the Windows Desktop version of Word. You can update the result of a field code by selecting it and pressing F9; You can insert a pair of the special "field code braces" {  } using ctrl-F9)

To start, select the first figure number in the main document and copy it using ctrl-C

In the diagram document, click in a paragraph (not in a diagram) and use Alt-Ctrl-V (or *Home tab-> Clipboard group->Paste dropdown->Paste-Special* ) to open the Paste Special dialog box.

Click the *Paste Link* button, select *Unformatted Text* in the list, and ensure the *Display as Icon* checkbox is not checked. Then click OK.

You should see either a copy of the figure number in the diagram document, or a field code that looks something like this:

```
{ LINK Word.Document.12 "C:\\xxx\\maindoc1.docx" "OLE_LINK1" \a \t }
```

The key to this whole procedure is that OLE_LINK1 is the name of a bookmark that Word has created in the main document to "cover" the figure number that you just copied. So if you insert a new Figure number in the main document before the one you've just linked to, the Bookmark remains the same so the the LINK links to the same place. But when you update the figure number in the main document, then update the LINK field in the diagram document, the number in the diagram document updates.

If you want to be able to see where Word has inserted these bookmarks, you can

- check *File->Options->Advanced->Show Document Content->Show Bookmarks*. Word then displays a grey pair of [ ] around each bookmarked area
- use *Insert->Links->Bookmark* to see a list of the bookmarks in the document. Select one and click Goto to select the bookmarked area.0

To check what's happened so far, go back into the main document and insert a new Figure number before the original one. Then use ctrl-A, F9 to update the figure numbers if necessary.

Go back into the diagram document. You should see that the LINK field result has already changed to 2 (because the `\a` in the LINK field says "automatically update the link"). But if not, select the field and press F9 to update its value. You should see "2".

Now insert a paragraph below the LINK field, and insert a graphic shape in the diagram document. (say, a rectangle). It's important that the "anchor" of the shape comes after the LINK field.

Right-click the shape and click `Edit Text` to display a text area in the middle of the shape. Copy/paste the LINK field in there, then type the digit 1 immediately after it. View the field results, and you should see "21"

In the main document, insert another Figure number before the first one, and update the field codes in there. You should see the number 3 and 31 in the diagram document now.

Turning back to your sample diagram, what that means is that you can put the number for each shape in a rectangle shape (or a text box) with no border, and get reasonably good automatic updating.

There are, unfortunately, a number of gotchas, including

- the LINK code contains the absolute path+name of the main document (with backslashes doubled up). Move the main document, and you may find that you have to modify all those paths. (Unfortunately, you cannot assign the path to a bookmark such as { mypath } then use { mypath } within the LINK field - Word just destroys nested fields in LINK fields.
- updating a lot of LINK fields can take Word a long time. IMO that is better avoided.

So instead of using the LINK field directly, it is IMO better to use some kind of reference to the LINK field. If the figure number is always a whole number, IMO it is easiest to use a SEQ field for that. So, select the first link you selected, then

- use ctrl-F9 to surround it with a pair of field braces, so you have

  ```
  { { LINK Word.Document.12 "C:\\xxx\\maindoc1.docx" "OLE_LINK1" \a \t } }
  ```
- add text so the field looks like this:

  ```
  { SEQ F \r{ LINK Word.Document.12 "C:\\xxx\\maindoc1.docx" "OLE_LINK1" \a \t } }
  ```
- Select that SEQ field and update it
- In the shape, delete the LINK field and replace it with

  ```
   { SEQ F \ c }
  ```

so the shape contains

```
    { SEQ F \ c }1
```

When you use Alt-F9 to view the field results, you should see 3 and 31

Now go back to your main document and insert another figure number at the beginning.

Go back to the diagram document. This time, you will see that neither number has changed.

This is because although the LINK field will have updated, the SEQ field has not.

So use ctrl-A to select the document and press F9. What I think you will now see is that the first SEQ field will show 4, but the one in the shape will still show 3. That's because Word doesn't update fields in the graphic layer when you do that.

In this case, you can still update those fields without code by going to File->Print then back again (this is because that causes Word to preview the document, and Print Preview normally causes most field types to update).

By way of explanation the `\r` in the `{ SEQ F \r { LINK ... } }` field makes Word "reset" the sequence named F to the value of the LINK field. Then the `\c` in the next `SEQ F` field says "use the current value of the F sequence". The advantage of this is that you can use F for every single Figure/shape in the diagram document.

So IMO that is a reasonable basis for a solution. There are still quite a lot of things that could go wrong, but trying to cover all of them here would not be helpful if the basic approach isn't going to work.

If instead of a single diagram document, you have one diagram document per Figure, you can still use this approach, but updating each diagram document is going to need you to open the document, update the fields, go to print preview, and save the document. If you are in a position to use VBA or scripting to automate that, so much the better.

The main thing that actually concerns me is if you have a lot of LINK fields in the same diagram document. In that case, it might be better to use a slightly different approach. But perhaps we could leave it there for now.

Comment: Thank you Yokki. That's a lot of effort you've put in there. I shall try this as soon as I get time and let you know. 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your separate document has the same order of figures as your main document and assuming you don't use chapter numbering but number your figures throughout, you might just use a simpler version of the answer of yokki without linking the documents.

1. Use captions to automatically number and renumber your figures.
2. Create your block label numbers by: "cross reference to figure in name number format""block number"

For Figure 1 and block number X this will look like Figure 1X.

Standard cross references to figures normally contain both name and number (if you use that option). There is no option to only cross reference the number of a figure (unless you select the option to not include the name of the caption when adding a new caption). You can however change this easily by changing the field codes.

Switching to field codes by alt + F9 will turn Figure 1X to { REF _Ref51339218 \h }X (ref number of course can be different)

By changing \h to # "0" you will change the name number format to number only:
{ REF _Ref51339218 \# "0"}X

Change back from field codes by alt+F9 and update all fields.

Tip: you can easily update all fields (captions, references etc.) by going to the print menu (without actually printing) and back to the document.

Now Figure 1X will have changed to 1X. You can use this in tables or text boxes for creating your block label numbers. You can just copy and paste this formatted 1X for all block label numbers for Figure 1 and change X to the designated number and you'll get a range from 11, 12, ... 1N for which the figure number will auto update when changing the order of your figures or adding figures in front. You will have to repeat the process for each figure.

Comment: Funnily enough, that is more or less the other approach I considered (although I've added yet another one into my existing Answer).. A couple of observations: To make a reference to the number only, all you really need do is bookmark the number part and use a plain REF field. Luckily, switching to print preview (File->Print) does update REFs to bookmarked text, but Print Preview doesn't update *all* fields.- e.g. it doesn't update REF fields where the bookmark was created by a SET field. Try { SET A 4 }{ A } for example.

Comment: Thank you JeeHaa. Again, very kind of you to spend time helping me with this. I shall try this approach too and see what works best. Will let you know.